# Python pandas to add a new column with split

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('911.csv')

df['Title'].head(5)

0     EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY
1    EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY
2        Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK
3     Traffic: CARDIAC EMERGENCY
4             Fire: DIZZINESS
```

make a new column with values before ':'
Result:

```
     Title                           Reason
0    EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY          EMS
1    EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY         EMS
2    Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK             Fire
3    Traffic: CARDIAC EMERGENCY      Traffic
4    Fire: DIZZINESS                 Fire
```

one solution with labda:

```
df['Reason'] = df['title'].apply(lambda title: title.split(':')[0])
```

can you please recommend without lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Reason"] = df["Title"].str.split(":", n=1).str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        Title   Reason
0      EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY      EMS
1     EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY      EMS
2         Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK     Fire
3  Traffic: CARDIAC EMERGENCY  Traffic
4             Fire: DIZZINESS     Fire
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `str.extract`

```
df['Reason'] = df['Title'].str.extract('(.*):')[0] 
#if you only want the `:` at the start of a sentence then use ^
# df['Title'].str.extract('^(.*):')[0] 

                        Title   Reason
0      EMS: BACK PAINS/INJURY      EMS
1     EMS: DIABETIC EMERGENCY      EMS
2         Fire: GAS-ODOR/LEAK     Fire
3  Traffic: CARDIAC EMERGENCY  Traffic
4             Fire: DIZZINESS     Fire
```